# writing jira query to find tickets where a set custom due date field has been set

Tags: jira, jql, custom-field-type

I’m trying to set up a filter than returns all the tickets where a custom Due Date field has been set AND then changed to some future date. So I don't want to get tickets back that have gone from unset to set, just where the date has been changed again after being set to an initial date.

Seems I can't use the CHANGED parameter on date fields.

Comment: Script runner (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) should be capable of changing custom filed after another one has been changed, You can use this additional custom field for queries.

Comment: You could do: dueDate was '' and dueDate changed from xyz to abc. Edit: that's right, dates are not supported in historical queries. I'd use something event based, listen for field change and then update another field, or use transitions for that.